# how to save angular 8 http request return value in a variable?

Tags: angular, http, httpclient

Im making a http call in angular as follows:

```
this.values = this.http.get("https://reqres.in/api/users/2").subscribe(data => console.log(data))
console.log(this.values)
```

now the console.log in the first line, which prints the data variable, prints the right return result, which is json format data. what im trying to do, is save that return value in the **this.values** variable, but its not working. **this.value** variable is returning an object of some weird information that has nothing to do with my return values.

The image below shows the console logs:

[image]

this.values returns the object at the top of the picture instead of the json at the bottom which is returned by console.log(data)

how can i save the http return value into **this.value** variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
this.http.get("https://reqres.in/api/users/2").subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
  this.values = data;
}
```

when you assign the `http.get` method to values, you're assigning a reference to the observable itself. you want to call the observable and change the value inside the callback that comes with subscribe.

Comment: using your method, when console.log, this.values, it gets printed as undefined. i dont understand why its not storing the data in it. i have declared the variable values as type any, do you think this might be an issue?

Comment: `this.values` will not be undefined when the response arrives. You just see undefined because you execute `console.log(this.value)` right after the http request. Move the line inside the subscription callback like `...subscribe(data => {this.values = data; console.log(data); console.log(this.values)});`

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for whoever is looking at this question.

The method below of getting and storing data lets you use **async and await** by using toPromise().

Using **async and await** in the function causes the code to wait for the return of the api.

```
async get(){
    var data = await this.http.get(this.url).toPromise(); //returns a json 
    var dataString = data.toString(); //Stringify the json to turn it to object
    var dataObj = JSON.parse(dataString);

    this.agenciesData = dataObj; //assign your variable to it
}
```