# Parsing IActionResult to get Object

Tags: c#, .net-core, angular8

I use the following code to call a .Net Core Web API Method. But the console logs `undefined`

```
 scan(file) {
    this.value = this.http.get("api/Scanner", { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe((result: any) => {
    this.value = result.Content;


    console.log(this.value);
  })
  }
```

---

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ScannerController : Controller
    {   [HttpGet]         
        public async Task<IActionResult> ScanAsync(string file_id)
        {
            //New Update //
            file_id = "./wwwroot/Upload/1";
            VirusTotal virusTotal = new VirusTotal("mykey");
            // virusTotal.UseTLS = true;         
            FileStream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(file_id);
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
           // stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);

            VirusTotalNet.Results.FileReport report = await virusTotal.GetFileReportAsync(fileBytes);
            bool hasFileBeenScannedBefore = report.ResponseCode == FileReportResponseCode.Present;

            Console.WriteLine("File has been scanned before: " + (hasFileBeenScannedBefore ? "Yes" : "No"));

            //If the file has been scanned before, the results are embedded inside the report.
            if (hasFileBeenScannedBefore)
            {
               return Ok(report);
            }
            else
            {
                ScanResult fileResult = await virusTotal.ScanFileAsync(fileBytes,"1");
                return Ok(fileResult);

            }

        }
    }
```

I need to display the results returned from VT as a Table.

Update:

JSON from network monitor

```
{"mD5":"a974beae1dcbdd038c0e319a1ebe3658","permalink":"https://www.virustotal.com/file/e9f1ab01fc0e4907e30cc259dd31f25bd77a46cb43daab8462c030286f75b7d1/analysis/1582697513/","positives":0,"resource":"e9f1ab01fc0e4907e30cc259dd31f25bd77a46cb43daab8462c030286f75b7d1","scan_date":"2020-02-26T06:11:53","scan_id":"e9f1ab01fc0e4907e30cc259dd31f25bd77a46cb43daab8462c030286f75b7d1-1582697513","scans":{"Bkav":{"detected":false,"version":"1.3.0.9899","result":null,"update":"20200221"},"TotalDefense":{"detected":false,"version":"37.1.62.1","result":null,"update":"20200225"},"MicroWorld-eScan":{"detected":false,"version":"14.0.409.0","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"FireEye":{"detected":false,"version":"29.7.0.0","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"CAT-QuickHeal":{"detected":false,"version":"14.00","result":null,"update":"20200225"},"McAfee":{"detected":false,"version":"6.0.6.653","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Malwarebytes":{"detected":false,"version":"3.6.4.335","result":null,"update":"20200225"},"Zillya":{"detected":false,"version":"2.0.0.4034","result":null,"update":"20200225"},"SUPERAntiSpyware":{"detected":false,"version":"5.6.0.1032","result":null,"update":"20200221"},"Sangfor":{"detected":false,"version":"1.0","result":null,"update":"20200221"},"K7AntiVirus":{"detected":false,"version":"11.96.33381","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"K7GW":{"detected":false,"version":"11.96.33380","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"BitDefenderTheta":{"detected":false,"version":"7.2.37796.0","result":null,"update":"20200211"},"F-Prot":{"detected":false,"version":"4.7.1.166","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Symantec":{"detected":false,"version":"1.11.0.0","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"ESET-NOD32":{"detected":false,"version":"20902","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Baidu":{"detected":false,"version":"1.0.0.2","result":null,"update":"20190318"},"TrendMicro-HouseCall":{"detected":false,"version":"10.0.0.1040","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Avast":{"detected":false,"version":"18.4.3895.0","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"ClamAV":{"detected":false,"version":"0.102.2.0","result":null,"update":"20200225"},"Kaspersky":{"detected":false,"version":"15.0.1.13","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"BitDefender":{"detected":false,"version":"7.2","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"NANO-Antivirus":{"detected":false,"version":"1.0.134.25032","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"AegisLab":{"detected":false,"version":"4.2","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Tencent":{"detected":false,"version":"1.0.0.1","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Ad-Aware":{"detected":false,"version":"3.0.5.370","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Emsisoft":{"detected":false,"version":"2018.12.0.1641","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Comodo":{"detected":false,"version":"32130","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"F-Secure":{"detected":false,"version":"12.0.86.52","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"DrWeb":{"detected":false,"version":"7.0.44.12030","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"VIPRE":{"detected":false,"version":"81804","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"TrendMicro":{"detected":false,"version":"11.0.0.1006","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"McAfee-GW-Edition":{"detected":false,"version":"v2017.3010","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"CMC":{"detected":false,"version":"1.1.0.977","result":null,"update":"20190321"},"Sophos":{"detected":false,"version":"4.98.0","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Cyren":{"detected":false,"version":"6.2.2.2","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Jiangmin":{"detected":false,"version":"16.0.100","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Avira":{"detected":false,"version":"8.3.3.8","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Fortinet":{"detected":false,"version":"6.2.142.0","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Antiy-AVL":{"detected":false,"version":"3.0.0.1","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Kingsoft":{"detected":false,"version":"2013.8.14.323","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Arcabit":{"detected":false,"version":"1.0.0.869","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"ViRobot":{"detected":false,"version":"2014.3.20.0","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"ZoneAlarm":{"detected":false,"version":"1.0","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Avast-Mobile":{"detected":false,"version":"200225-00","result":null,"update":"20200225"},"Microsoft":{"detected":false,"version":"1.1.16800.2","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"TACHYON":{"detected":false,"version":"2020-02-26.01","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"AhnLab-V3":{"detected":false,"version":"3.17.1.26513","result":null,"update":"20200225"},"VBA32":{"detected":false,"version":"4.3.0","result":null,"update":"20200225"},"ALYac":{"detected":false,"version":"1.1.1.5","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"MAX":{"detected":false,"version":"2019.9.16.1","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Zoner":{"detected":false,"version":"1.0.0.1","result":null,"update":"20200225"},"Rising":{"detected":false,"version":"25.0.0.24","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Yandex":{"detected":false,"version":"5.5.2.24","result":null,"update":"20200223"},"Ikarus":{"detected":false,"version":"0.1.5.2","result":null,"update":"20200225"},"MaxSecure":{"detected":false,"version":"1.0.0.1","result":null,"update":"20200225"},"GData":{"detected":false,"version":"A:25.24989B:26.17816","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"AVG":{"detected":false,"version":"18.4.3895.0","result":null,"update":"20200226"},"Panda":{"detected":false,"version":"4.6.4.2","result":null,"update":"20200225"},"Qihoo-360":{"detected":false,"version":"1.0.0.1120","result":null,"update":"20200226"}},"shA1":"91dd5bd55ffde207c110eddc42480c56d10b3f33","shA256":"e9f1ab01fc0e4907e30cc259dd31f25bd77a46cb43daab8462c030286f75b7d1","total":60,"response_code":1,"verbose_msg":"Scan finished, information embedded"}
```

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the response received from the server. At the moment the question title seems to describe an XY problem.

Comment: @John How should i do that?

Comment: Use your browser's debugger to inspect the network request.

Comment: `this.value = result.content` with low case

Comment: @Fabio Does not fix the issue ...

Comment: log actual value `console.log(result)` to see what you are getting, Why you are setting `this.value` twice?

Comment: @Fabio Still `undefined`

Comment: @John The network debugger shows proper value in JSON format.

Comment: Then your issue is with the client side, and not related to IActionResult. Can you include your JSON?

Comment: @John Please see update

Comment: The JSON object doesn't contain a field "content", so `undefined` is correct.

Comment: @techno, jos `console.log(result)` printing "undefined", then your original code should throw an exception `result.Content` where `result` is undefined.

Comment: @Fabio How can i fix this?

Comment: Check if result has any value?

Comment: @Osaf Console prints undefined.

Comment: You sure api sending the object? try debuggin in api level! also make sure to log result not result.Content.

Comment: @Osaf Please see the above comment on network debugging.I have tried directly printing without content.

Comment: @Osaf The values are printed in console if the printing is done within the block   
 ` this.http.get("api/Scanner/").subscribe(result => {
      this.value = result;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.value));
    }); `

Comment: i was recreating the problem as you mentioned but I think you found it why it was undefined

Comment: @Osaf No.. why it is undefined ?

Comment: i think it because of the way you were returning the data.Can i answer the question ?

Comment: @Osaf sure.... please

Comment: @John Please see my comment above.

Comment: Why are you expecting a field "content" when your JSON response doesn't have that field? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @John Should i create interfaces for the scan result?

Comment: If the field doesn't exist in the JSON response, then creating interfaces won't make it exist in Javascript/Typescript.

Comment: I understand that.What i'm asking is if i need to display the scan data in a table is it necessary to create `interface` can i simply use JSON.parse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http calls are async so you get the Observeable. And observeable needs to be subscribe as you did but you cannot return the observeable simply like that 
you're not assigning value that you want but you are assigning a reference to the observable itself.

```
 this.value = this.http.get("api/Scanner", { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe((result: any) => {});
```

> when you assign the http.get method to values, you're assigning a
>   reference to the observable itself. you want to call the observable
>   and change the value inside the callback that comes with subscribe.

I found this explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59061299/12409748)

You can use pipe/map operator to return value like this

```
scan(file) {
return this.http.get("api/Scanner", { responseType: 'text' }).pipe(

 map(result => {
      //Logic or
     return result;
  })
 )
 }
```

Comment: Actually the process is complete and the controller returns ...

Comment: yes but assigning value like that won't work .this.value = this.http.get("api/Scanner", { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe((result: any) => {
    this.value = result.Content; you can read the documentation you cannot return the value like that and also you were trying to assign this.value twice. it's just my understanding tho

Comment: you can use method to return the value with map operator and assign it to this.value it's easy and more friendly approach.

Comment: I update the answer i think it will give you the explanation